# Root cause of deadlock?

Tags: oracle, deadlock, trace

I see below details for one of the deadlock detected in oracle 12g trace files but i am not getting why deadlock is happening here ?

Deadlock happens when thread 1 acquires lock on table1 or table rows but wait for table 2 rows  and at the same time thread 2 acquires lock on table 2 rows byt wait for table1 rows

But i do not see the details which session is acquired the lock on which table and waiting for which resource . Any help what are the object which got locked here and
cause of it  ?

```
Deadlock graph:
                                          ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name                             process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-00290010-00015F75-00000000-00000000        295    1200     X            288       10           X
TX-00570012-00005D9B-00000000-00000000        288       10     X            295    1200           X

session 1200: DID 0001-0127-00014421    session 10: DID 0001-0120-00016BD1 
session 10: DID 0001-0120-00016BD1  session 1200: DID 0001-0127-00014421 

Rows waited on:
  Session 1200: obj - rowid = 00051348 - BABRNIAARAAKfNLAAl
...
  Session 10: obj - rowid = 000514F2 - BABRTyAAJAAKWbIAAY
....

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
....
  current SQL:
  update employee set name=:1 
----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=5dfr2prw60rh1) -----
update department set address =:1 where id=:1 
===================================================
```

Comment: you are saying the 2 updates causing the updates ? if you stopped one update , will that leave the lock ?

Comment: Post here, please, the complete DDLs of both `employee` and `department` tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output says the current session is trying to update a locked record in the department table (the "information for THIS session" output). The other session is trying to update every employee record (the "information for the OTHER waiting sessions" output).  The current session must have updated a record in the employee table, blocking the other session, while the other session updated the record the current session is trying to update.

I assume this is some sort of exercise to cause a deadlock, since you're setting every employee record to the same name.

Comment: @Doockie is there any utility/tool which can read oracle trace file and provide the report ? I remember Microsoft management studio used to have it when i used to work on sql server